# Problem installing apt-get on CentOS 5.5

Tags: centos, aptitude

Background: I'm wanting to move away from Apache and came across [this article](http://interfacelab.com/nginx-php-fpm-apc-awesome/) which walks through an install of nginx, PHP-FPM and APC. On trying to follow these instructions on my user account of my host I ran into a problem: lack of apt-get and broken yum. So, I tried to build apt-get from source:

```
wget http://apt-rpm.org/releases/apt-0.5.15lorg3.tar.bz2
tar -vxf apt-0.5.15lorg3.tar.bz2
cd apt-0.5.15lorg3
./configure --prefix=$HOME
```

This is where I run into an issue:

```
...
checking db1/db.h usability... no
checking db1/db.h presence... no
checking for db1/db.h... no
checking rpm/rpmlib.h usability... no
checking rpm/rpmlib.h presence... no
checking for rpm/rpmlib.h... no
configure: error: Can't find rpmlib.h
```

Any ideas on how to solve this or get around the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "broken yum"? Is it not finding the package, or is it throwing you Python errors?

You can always try cleaning the yum cache, it fixes a lot of issues:

```
#yum clean all
```

If the main package manager on your OS is broken, the last thing you want to do is install another package manager, especially from source. [Dependency hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell) is the last thing you need. I'd recommend trying to fix yum first and foremost.

Comment: When I try to use yum I'm getting the error: "Config Error: Error accessing file for config file://///etc/yum.repos.d/WebFaction.repo". I'll take your recommendation on board though, thanks!

Comment: Ah, you're with webfaction hosting. What are the permissions for that file when you do a `ls -la /etc/yum.repos.d` ? http://www.pastebin.com

Comment: @Nev, what was your final solution?

Comment: Thanks for the help John. Basically any package manager is a no-go so I've been working with the support guys at Webfaction to build nginx etc. from source. Which is, er, "fun"!

Answer (score 1):

1. Download and install the rpm forge release, which will enable YUM to access:
         *

   ```
       wget http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm
       rpm -i rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm
   ```
2. After this is installed (it takes a long time), you can install APT.
3. You should now be able to use apt-get and install the apt repositories. You will have to add your sources at /etc/apt/sources.list.d

[This](http://support.rightscale.com/06-FAQs/FAQ_0063_-_How_can_I_use_apt-get_on_CentOS_based_images%3F) link might be helpful.